# How to rename a column in pandas if column name has space. For example : Nom restaurant

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to rename my column name, but however it does not change because of space. my column name is **Nom restaurant** i already have tried

```
df.rename(columns = {'Nom restaurant':'Names', 'x_coor':'X_coor','y_coor':'Y_coor','Weight':'Weights'}, inplace =True)
```

Actually my goal is change only mentioned column name, but after many try i failed, and using this piece of code. All column names changed except first one. The problem is about space in first column name.

Output of `df.head`

```
Nom restaurant  X_coor  Y_coor
0   ARBUSTES    48.828431   2.309284
1   CAULAINCOURT    48.889552   2.339419
2   MARCHE DE L'EUROPE  48.877284   2.313452
3   LA QUINTINIE    48.839301   2.30718
4   AU MAIRE    48.864445   2.357714
```

Output of `df.columns`

`Index(['Nom restaurant ', 'X_coor', 'Y_coor'], dtype='object')`

Comment: You're saying column name is `Nom Restaurant` but in code, it's written as `Nom restaurant`. Notice the `R`

Comment: I think you are missing the uppercase in `Restaurant` otherwise it should work I believe

Comment: it was mistyping, i correct it

Comment: can you show us the output of `df.head()`?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity see post again, pls

Comment: what about `df.columns`? It kinda looks like `Nom` and `restaurant` are different columns, but I'm not sure

Comment: @ignoring_gravity no it's not. i am sure that the problem is about space in ''Nom restaurant"

Comment: OK, got it, you're missing the space at the _end_ of restaurant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do

```
df = df.rename(columns = {'Nom restaurant ':'Names', 'x_coor':'X_coor','y_coor':'Y_coor','Weight':'Weights'})
```