# How to rename a column in pandas if column name has space

Tags: pandas, rename

I know that if a column is comprised of two or more words and I want to rename it, I have to use a space after the last word. For example:

This one won`t change "TOTAL VALUE" to "TOTAL_VALUE":
housing_df = housing_df.rename(columns={'TOTAL VALUE': 'TOTAL_VALUE'}) # explicit

But this one will:
housing_df = housing_df.rename(columns={'TOTAL VALUE ': 'TOTAL_VALUE'}) # explicit

How is that "space" working?

I found this link but does not say why one works but not the other.
[How to rename a column in pandas if column name has space. For example : Nom restaurant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543215/how-to-rename-a-column-in-pandas-if-column-name-has-space-for-example-nom-res)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When renaming a column with spaces, you need to ensure that the new column name includes the space character in the appropriate position to match the spaces in the original column name. This way, pandas can accurately identify and rename the desired column.

In the first case, `housing_df = housing_df.rename(columns={'TOTAL VALUE': 'TOTAL_VALUE'})`, you are trying to rename the column `'TOTAL VALUE'` to `'TOTAL_VALUE'`. However, since the column name does not contain a trailing space, it will not match the original column name, and the renaming won't occur.

In the second case, `housing_df = housing_df.rename(columns={'TOTAL VALUE ': 'TOTAL_VALUE'})`, you are including a trailing space in the new column name `'TOTAL_VALUE '`. This space character matches the space in the original column name, allowing pandas to correctly identify the column to be renamed.

A trailing space refers to a space character that appears at the end of a string. In the context of renaming columns in pandas, a trailing space is a space character that exists at the end of the column name.

Comment: Thank you very much. What is the purpose of that trailing space? Is that something pandas assumes at the end of each phrase or that is because I`m reading a .csv file (and there is a whitespace at the end of each phrase?)

Comment: @Jaime The trailing space in the new column name is not something that pandas assumes or adds automatically. It is entirely dependent on the specific column name you provide when renaming the column. The presence of a trailing space in the new column name is necessary only when you want to match and replace a column name that contains a trailing space. If the original column name contains a space character at the end, you must include that trailing space in the new column name to perform an accurate renaming.